# SQLAlchemy setting server_default to values of other columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a pre-populated database with two columns. Column 'A' is a unique id which is just an integer, and column 'B' is just some string.

I want to create a new column that is simply the string concatenation of the two columns.

How would I do this using `server_default`?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using as a backend?  And would a computed column be OK or it must be a default?

Comment: Postgresql. I don't mind how the values are calculated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Computed column to hold the value:

```py
import sqlalchmy as sa

tbl = sa.Table(
    't73280376',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('a', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('b', sa.String),
    sa.Column('c', sa.String, sa.Computed('a::text || b')),
)
```

Note that the column cannot be updated independently of `a` and `b`.

Passing the same expression to `server_default`

```
sa.Column('c', sa.String, server_default=sa.text('a::text || b'))
```

does not generate valid DDL:

```
test# CREATE TABLE t73280376 (
test(#         a SERIAL NOT NULL, 
test(#         b VARCHAR, 
test(#         c VARCHAR DEFAULT a::text || b, 
test(#         PRIMARY KEY (a)
test(# )
test-# ;
ERROR:  cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 4:         c VARCHAR DEFAULT a::text || b,
```